# Python Kivy - Adding a GridLayout to a BoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to create an UI with Buttons on top and a few Labels on bottom and if the labels exceeds the height it should be scrollable.

Something like this:

[image: Basic Layout]

So far this is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyApp(App):

    main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    top_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

    scrollView = ScrollView()
    gridLayout = GridLayout()
    gridLayout.cols = 1
    gridLayout.minimum_height = 10
    gridLayout.padding = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    scrollView.add_widget(gridLayout)

    main_layout.add_widget(top_layout)
    main_layout.add_widget(scrollView)

    def btn_create(self, instance):
        self.gridLayout.add_widget(Label(text='test'))

    def btn_edit(self, instance):
        pass

    def btn_delete(self, instance):
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.top_layout.size_hint=(1, .1)

        # Button 'Erstellen'
        btnCreate = Button()
        btnCreate.text = 'Erstellen'
        btnCreate.bind(on_press=self.btn_create)

        # Button 'Bearbeiten'
        btnEdit = Button()
        btnEdit.text = 'Bearbeiten'
        btnEdit.bind(on_press=self.btn_edit)

        # Button 'Löschen'
        btnDelete = Button()
        btnDelete.text = 'Löschen'
        btnDelete.bind(on_press=self.btn_delete)

        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnCreate)
        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnEdit)
        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnDelete)

        return self.main_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I added a GridLayout to a ScrollView, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can i make a scrollable list?

Comment: what is the meaning of *but this doesn't seem to work.*? 
that's very generic, be more detailed, read [ask]

Comment: I can add a Label to the GridLayout, but it will not create a scrollable List. https://imgur.com/lynkv3j

Comment: That adds to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the size_hint_y of the GridLayout to None so that the height does not depend on the ScrollView and the size is minimum equal to the size of the GridLayout. On the other hand the Label must have size_hint_y to None so that the height does not depend on the GridLayout.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyApp(App):

    main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    top_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

    scrollView = ScrollView()
    gridLayout = GridLayout(size_hint_y=None)

    gridLayout.cols = 1
    gridLayout.padding = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    gridLayout.bind(minimum_height=gridLayout.setter('height'))
    scrollView.add_widget(gridLayout)

    main_layout.add_widget(top_layout)
    main_layout.add_widget(scrollView)

    def btn_create(self, instance):
        self.gridLayout.add_widget(Label(text='test', size_hint_y=None))

    def btn_edit(self, instance):
        pass

    def btn_delete(self, instance):
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.top_layout.size_hint=(1, .1)

        # Button 'Erstellen'
        btnCreate = Button()
        btnCreate.text = 'Erstellen'
        btnCreate.bind(on_press=self.btn_create)

        # Button 'Bearbeiten'
        btnEdit = Button()
        btnEdit.text = 'Bearbeiten'
        btnEdit.bind(on_press=self.btn_edit)

        # Button 'Löschen'
        btnDelete = Button()
        btnDelete.text = 'Löschen'
        btnDelete.bind(on_press=self.btn_delete)

        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnCreate)
        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnEdit)
        self.top_layout.add_widget(btnDelete)

        return self.main_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```